# Cheapest permutation calculation

Tags: algorithm, mongodb-query, permutation

I have a collection of documents. The relevant structure of the object for this question would be:

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98391"),
    ...
    "type": "a",
    "components":{
        "component2": 20,
        "component3": 10,
    },
    "price": 123
    ...
}
```

I'm currently using an old set of code that I wrote a while ago to find the cheapest permutation of a combination needed. I'm not sure if this is possible to do with just a query, but thought I would ask before moving any further.

Specifics: There are 10 possible "type"'s ( a-j ). There are 4 possible "component"'s types. Items will have at least 1 "component", but can have  up to 2. They will never have more than 2. While the types are limited to 2, the value ( "grade" ) of the components can range. So either exactly 1 or exactly 2 components, with any possible combination of component values/grades.

There are 10k records, and what I'm needing to do is find the the lowest possible price, having at least one of each type, that yields me at least my desired grade for either the one or two components I enter.

The expected result would always have one of each type ( 10 total ).

In layman's I'd be asking the data set for the cheapest combination of component2's that exceed 200. Or, the cheapest combination of component1/component3 that exceed a 150 component1 grade **and** exceed a 150 component3 grade.

Again though that combination is restricted because it must have exactly/only one of each type. So a better price could certainly be achieved if there was 10 type "a"'s, but it would need to be 1 "a", 1 "b", etc.

I don't think it is, but is it possible this could somehow be achieved with a query alone?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do we need to look at the components, if all which is interesting is the price and to have one of each type?

Comment: As the description outlines there is a minimum grade required in combination with the price and type.